# Mac os El Capitan не видит смартфоны

Tags: macos, vmware, внешние-устройства

Какая-то непонятная проблема конфигурации. У меня есть `mac os El Capitan` на `vmware`. Подключаю к операционной системе флешку - всё нормально: и читает, и записывает (флешка отображается на рабочем столе). Подключаю `ipod` - устройство даже не отображается. Подключаю смартфон `nokia x5` - тоже не отображается.

Почему операционная система на виртуалке не видит смартфоны?

**Update**: Если быть точнее, ОС реагирует на подключение\отключение смартфонов. Просто не отображает на рабочем столе. Возможно она просто отображает их в другом месте. Весь вопрос - где?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме

Comment: А ПО железа которое блокирует взаимодействие ОС и периферийных устройств разве не является тематикой сайта?  ИМХО ipod подключенный к Xcode - это однозначно средство для разработки.

Comment: Открыл вопрос повторно. Пожалуйста, уточните формулировку. Сейчас вопрос не выглядит относящимся к тематике сайта.

Comment: @Nicolas Chabanovsky а как это сделать? Приведите пример, пожалуйста, а то не ясно что не так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решено. Нужно смотреть настройки параметры виртуальной машины. В строке `USB-контроллер`поменять совместимость с `USB-3.0` на `USB-2.0`. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

В случае с iPod, посмотри iTunes. А вообще, посмотри в корневом каталоге (в терминале) команды для работы можно тут посмотреть (http://osxh.ru/content/spisok-terminalnyh-komand-os-x) директорию /dev но тут кратенько есть - http://macosworld.ru/wp-content/uploads/2008/07/files-and-folders2.jpg

Comment: посмотрел команды. И чего с ними делать?